SonarScanner java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
Hello I am using sonarqube server version 7.9 and sonarscanner version 5.18. When I try to analyze my C# code static code, I get the following error.
I tried all versions of Sonarqube from 5.XX and 4.XX
I am starting
- sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.15.1.88158-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"my_project" /d:sonar.host.url="http://my_host:my_port" /d:sonar.login="my_token" /d:sonar.exclusions="**/*.js,**/*.css"
- dotnet build
- sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.15.1.88158-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
        at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.uriToAbsolutePath(SarifParser10.java:225)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleLocation(SarifParser10.java:175)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleResultFileElement(SarifParser10.java:146)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleLocationsElement(SarifParser10.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssue(SarifParser10.java:107)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.handleIssues(SarifParser10.java:95)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.accept(SarifParser10.java:65)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.sarif.SarifParser10.accept(SarifParser10.java:39)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.RoslynDataImporter.importRoslynReports(RoslynDataImporter.java:54)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.DotNetSensor.executeInternal(DotNetSensor.java:105)
        at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.DotNetSensor.execute(DotNetSensor.java:73)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:62)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:29.653s
INFO: Final Memory: 14M/60M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
ERROR:
The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
09:25:48.523  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

